# How to check if the url website is emebedable with iframe or not with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question would like to ask you , is it possible to check if the url of website is embeddable with Iframe or not? I have try many website in Iframe,and it has shown the good result, which means it work but just a few website is not embeddable, although I would like to ask you how to alert if the website is not embeddable with jQuery.

eg. 
   1- http://www.forbes.com/video/2590105606001/ (show blank in Iframe)
   2- http://news.sabay.com.kh/article/260880 (show result in Iframe)
so, how could I solve the first (number 1) problem.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3076648/2518525) might be of interest

Comment: nothing you can do without doing it manually